# How to use Linq and the IN clause

Tags: linq

Here is my code

```
if (catid != 0)
            posts = posts.Where(x => x.catid IN '1,8,2,109,23');
```

The **in** in this code shows as a syntax error. Is there a way to fix this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must use another list to compare too.

```
List<int> cadIdFoundList = new List<int>();

cadIdFoundList.Add(1);
cadIdFoundList.Add(8);
// etc. . . 

posts.Where(x => cadIdFoundList.Contains(x.catId));
```

Answer (score 5):

```
int[] ids = new int[] { 1, 8, 2, 109, 23 };
var query = posts.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.catid));
```

Rob Conery has [discussed](http://blog.wekeroad.com/2008/02/27/creating-in-queries-with-linq-to-sql/) this topic before.

Answer (score 2):

Or even more simple:

```
var query = posts.Where(x => new[] { 1, 8, 2, 109, 23 }.Contains(x.catid));
```

Comment: It's a shame we have to put that new[] there.  Wouldn't it be cool if we could just do {1, 7, 3, 5}.Contains instead?  :D

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something more like:

```
HashSet<int> categories = new HashSet<int>() { 1, 2, 8, 23, 109};
posts = posts.Where(post => categories.Contains(post.catid));
```