# "In clause" by LINQ to SQL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I want to use something like "In clause" of SQL SERVER.
Here are my models:

```
public partial class StationEvaluationBooks
{
    public int StationEvaluationBookID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> StationEvaluationID { get; set; }

    public virtual StationEvaluation StationEvaluation { get; set; }
    ...
 }
public partial class StationEvaluation
{
    public StationEvaluation()
    {
        this.StationEvaluationBooks = new HashSet<StationEvaluationBooks>();
    }
    public int StationEvaluationID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<StationEvaluationBooks> StationEvaluationBooks { get; set; }
    ...
 }
```

I used the following code to implement "In clause" by LINQ but I got error:

```
        StationsEntities db = new StationsEntities();

        var stationevaluations = db.StationEvaluation;
       //some conditions:
        stationevaluations = stationevaluations.Where(/*condition*/);
       ..

        var result = from c in db.StationEvaluationBooks
                       where stationevaluations.Contains(c.StationEvaluationID)
                       select c;
```

Error:      'System.Data.Entity.DbSet' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.Contains(System.Linq.ParallelQuery, TSource)' has some invalid arguments

**EDIT:**
I want to get those books that are related to the selected evaluations in stationevaluations variable.

Comment: What are you trying to select? All books? All books with some condition?

Comment: All books with some condition

Comment: stationevaluation variable includes some records that I want to use them in StationEvaluationBooks(based on StationEvaluationID). I  want to get those books that have the above StationEvaluationIDs.

Comment: I already updated answer, see below

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Linq and the IN clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2015794/how-to-use-linq-and-the-in-clause)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Getting books related to selected stations:

```
var ids = db.StationEvaluation.Where(/*condition*/)
            .Select(s => s.StationEvaluationID)
            .ToList();

var result = from b in db.StationEvaluationBooks
             where b.StationEvaluationID.HasValue &&
                   ids.Contains(b.StationEvaluationID.Value)
             select b;
```

Or best option

```
var result = db.StationEvaluation.Where(/*condition*/)
               .SelectMany(s => s.StationEvaluationBooks);
```

Comment: @BahmanNikkhahan similar is not the same. That error can't exist if you are using my code. Keep in mind that `ids` has only identifiers of stations. Also see last sample with `SelectMany`

Comment: @BahmanNikkhahan there is no calls to Contains of DbSet in my code. You can't have same error

Comment: Yes you're right, but I think I can't show the exact error. Some characters are deleted!

Comment: @BahmanNikkhahan Have you tried `SelectMany`? Also I've added `ToList()` on ids. There is nothing pointing to DbSet now

Comment: The exact error:'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<MainProject.Areas.Study_Stations.Models.StationEvaluation>' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.Contains<TSource>(System.Linq.ParallelQuery<TSource>, TSource)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: @BahmanNikkhahan I think you are still using your code. Verify carefully what code is really executed

Comment: Ok, this is really starting to confuse me. @BahmanNikkhahan could you please post some more code?

Comment: @IronMan84 looks like he has code on server side, but server still uses old assembly

Comment: @lazyberezovsky That would make a ton of sense, actually.

Comment: It's been solved. Thank you. That was my mistake! your code works great.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your most recent update, how about this:

```
var stationEvaluations = db.StationEvaluation.Where(/*condition*/)
                                             .Select(st => st.StationEvaluationID);

var result = from c in db.StationEvaluationBooks
                       where stationEvaluations.Contains(c.StationEvaluationID)
                       select c;
```

Comment: It didn't change anything.